# Moving an agent from Wait block to correct destination

Tags: wait, anylogic

I have developed a method to release agents from Wait block just-in-time (see picture). And it works perfectly when I have one production line only with a direct link between Wait block and this line. But I have no idea at all how to move agents to the right production line when there are two or more of it. Can anybody help me to create a code to move an agent to a line which generates an order for this agent? I think I need to write in an agent a number of Enter where this agent should follow to but I don't know how to do it based on my Java code. Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leObV.png) I think Wait block should have some function to send an agent to right destination. But I failed to find it. Also I checked out a load of information on SOF and didn't find similar tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define where your agent needs to go in the `SelectOutputIn` block by setting 'Select output: By explicit choice' then writing the code that selects the correct `SelectOutputOut` block.

*PS: I mostly use `Exit`-`Enter` pairs instead, because they give you much more flexibility when you need to send agents from one flow to another*